# Spark submit with Yarn Rest API [Spark unable to resolve namenode HA name]

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I'm submitting spark job via yarn rest api call but getting this exception, spark is unable to resolve the namenode HA name, while submitting spark job from yarn launcher and getting failed on the launcher itself:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException: nameservice1
at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.buildTokenService(SecurityUtil.java:414)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createNonHAProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:164)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:129)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:448)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:410)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:128)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2308)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:87)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2342)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2324)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:351)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:194)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(JobSubmissionFiles.java:103)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:980)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:974)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1438)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:974)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:948)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1410)
at org.apache.hadoop.examples.SleepJob.run(SleepJob.java:174)
at org.apache.hadoop.examples.SleepJob.run(SleepJob.java:237)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
at org.apache.hadoop.examples.SleepJob.main(SleepJob.java:165)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:72)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:144)
at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:64)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: nameservice1
```

Submit command:

```
{
  "am-container-spec": {
    "commands": {
      "command": "JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java7/ org.apache.hadoop.yarn.applications.distributedshell.ApplicationMaster  --jar spark-job.jar --class MySparkJob --arg --retry --arg false --arg --counter --arg 10"
    }, 
    "local-resources": {
      "entry": [
        {
          "key": "spark-job.jar", 
          "value": {
            "resource": "hdfs:///spark-job.jar", 
            "size": 3214567, 
            "timestamp": 1452408423000, 
            "type": "FILE", 
            "visibility": "APPLICATION"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }, 
  "application-id": "application_11111111111111_0001", 
  "application-name": "test",
  "application-type": "Spark"   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the thing is, spark will search for hadoop configuration files on the classpath and will set hadoop configurations by itself from those files and hence would be able to resolve namenode HA name:
So need to set `HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf`

Working submit command:

```
{
  "am-container-spec": {
    "commands": {
      "command": "JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java7/ HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf org.apache.hadoop.yarn.applications.distributedshell.ApplicationMaster  --jar spark-job.jar --class MySparkJob --arg --retry --arg false --arg --counter --arg 10"
    }, 
    "local-resources": {
      "entry": [
        {
          "key": "spark-job.jar", 
          "value": {
            "resource": "hdfs:///spark-job.jar", 
            "size": 3214567, 
            "timestamp": 1452408423000, 
            "type": "FILE", 
            "visibility": "APPLICATION"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }, 
  "application-id": "application_11111111111111_0001", 
  "application-name": "test",
  "application-type": "Spark"   
}
```